# How to remove leading and trailing spaces from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have the following input:

```
string txt = "                   i am a string                                    "
```

I want to remove space from start of starting and end from a string.

The result should be:  `"i am a string"`

How can I do this in c#?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx)

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

Usage:

```
txt = txt.Trim();
```

If this isn't working then it highly likely that the "spaces" aren't spaces but some other non printing or white space character, possibly tabs. In this case you need to use the `String.Trim` method which takes an array of characters:

```
  char[] charsToTrim = { ' ', '\t' };
  string result = txt.Trim(charsToTrim);
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx)

You can add to this list as and when you come across more space like characters that are in your input data. Storing this list of characters in your database or configuration file would also mean that you don't have to rebuild your application each time you come across a new character to check for.

**NOTE**

As of .NET 4 [`.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8) removes any character that [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Char_IsWhiteSpace_System_Char_) returns `true` for so it should work for most cases you come across. Given this, it's probably not a good idea to replace this call with the one that takes a list of characters you have to maintain.

It would be better to call the default `.Trim()` and *then* call the method with your list of characters.

Answer (score 20):

You can use:

- [String.TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) - Removes all leading occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object.
- [String.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) - Removes all trailing occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object.
- [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) - combination of the two functions above

**Usage:**

```
string txt = "                   i am a string                                    ";
char[] charsToTrim = { ' ' };    
txt = txt.Trim(charsToTrim)); // txt = "i am a string"
```

**EDIT:**

```
txt = txt.Replace(" ", ""); // txt = "iamastring"
```

Answer (score 11):

I really don't understand some of the hoops the other answers are jumping through.

```
var myString = "    this    is my String ";
var newstring = myString.Trim(); // results in "this is my String"
var noSpaceString = myString.Replace(" ", ""); // results in "thisismyString";
```

It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 5):

```
txt = txt.Trim();
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can split your string to string array, splitting by space and then add every item of string array to empty string.
May be this is not the best and fastest method, but you can try, if other answer aren't what you whant.

Comment: this works for replacing spaces that are not at the beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

[text.Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) is to be used

```
string txt = "                   i am a string                                    ";
txt = txt.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Trim method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main()
    {
        // A.
        // Example strings with multiple whitespaces.
        string s1 = "He saw   a cute\tdog.";
        string s2 = "There\n\twas another sentence.";

        // B.
        // Create the Regex.
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\s+");

        // C.
        // Strip multiple spaces.
        string s3 = r.Replace(s1, @" ");
        Console.WriteLine(s3);

        // D.
        // Strip multiple spaces.
        string s4 = r.Replace(s2, @" ");
        Console.WriteLine(s4);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

OUTPUT:

He saw a cute dog.
There was another sentence.
He saw a cute dog.

Answer (score -3):

You Can Use

```
string txt = "                   i am a string                                    ";
txt = txt.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
```

Output is "i am a string"

Comment: @john: There's nothing wrong with trying to get reputation from answering old questions, as long as the answers are *good*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Indeed. Sorry if I came across as implying anything other than that. Reading my comment back now it does sound rather blanket. Of course good anwers to old questions are fine.

Comment: @john : I am not expect reputation.If you need trim left what is the solution?that is why i mention here.sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: If you need left trim, there will already be a question for it. If there is not, you can create a q/a style question which you both ask and answer.