# Removing multiple whitespace, c#

Tags: c#, whitespace

what I'm trying to do is I'm trying to reduce whitespace sizes to 1 characters (removing any unneeded whitespace. How should I deal with the task ?

PS.: NO Regex

EDIT.: Thanks, already succeeded, thanks for the split+join suggestion. Unfortunately, can't upvote any of the responses as frustrated teens have already -repspammed me for asking "a question too simple for the website"

EDIT2.: How do I make sure it doesn't remove a space in the front of the sentence, in case there is one ?

Comment: Have you tried anything, or just requested solution here? Doing it with for loop is not a rocket science ...

Comment: split the text based on the text and then join all the strings if the string length is greater than one.

Comment: I've tried going for sentence = sentence.Replace(" ", " "); but that's a terrible idea

Comment: how about `var res = string.Join(" ", myString.Split(new char []{' '} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`

Comment: @Damith Will work, but I don't think that creating an array of strings and then rejoin them is very good for performance (expecially with long texts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
string.Join(" ", 
   myString.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

**Edit**

As extension

```
    public static string RemoveWhiteSpaces(this string s)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
myString.RemoveWhiteSpaces();
```

Answer (score 4):

An extension for the string class

```
public static string RemoveExcessSpaces(this string str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
    bool first = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\r':
            case '\n':
            case '\t':
            case ' ':
                if(first)
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                    continue;
                break;
            default:
                sb.Append(c);
                first = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Call it with

```
string result = "This is   a   test whit \t\t\r\n    multiple spaces";
result = result.RemoveExcessSpaces();
```

[Giving credit to the original idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203607/fastest-way-to-remove-white-spaces-in-string)

Of course the set of chars that should be considered whitespaces could be defined passing a list of chars, (or using [Char.IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx)) but perhaps this could be better for the performance

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code:

```
public static String WhiteSpaceReducer(String value) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;

  Boolean wasWhiteSpace = false;
  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (Char Ch in value) 
    if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(Ch)) {
      if (!wasWhiteSpace)
        Sb.Append(Ch);

      wasWhiteSpace = true;
    }
    else {
      wasWhiteSpace = false;
      Sb.Append(Ch);
    }

  return Sb.ToString();
}


...

String test = "   test   me  out  ";
String result = WhiteSpaceReducer(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this

```
string myString = "I'm too            lazy for research.";
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: `"I'm_too____lazy_for____research."` what about this?

Comment: but when in one place is three or more whitespace? ;)

Comment: This would remove _all_ spaces, no?

Comment: Yup, this removes every single space, which isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: @TheProvost Should work, but note the "NO Regex" in the question :)