# How to remove white spaces from sentence?

Tags: c#, trim, removing-whitespace

I want to remove all  white spaces from string variable which contains a sentence.
Here is my code:

```
string s = "This text contains white spaces";
string ns = s.Trim();
```

Variable "sn" should look like "Thistextcontainswhitespaces", but it doesn't(method s.Trim() isn't working). What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: what is the  language?

Comment: I'm using c# language

Comment: The Trim method removes from the current string all leading and trailing white-space characters. Leading white-space characters are whitespace characters which occur before all characters in the string that are not whitespace. Trailing white-space characters are whitespace characters which occur after all characters in the string that are not whitespace. Calling Trim() on the string "  this is  " would return "this is".

Comment: Check this link as well `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203607/fastest-way-to-remove-white-spaces-in-string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `Trim` usually just removes whitespace from the begin and end of a string.

```
string s = "     String surrounded with whitespace     ";
string ns = s.Trim();
```

Will create this string: `"String surrounded with whitespace"`

To remove all spaces from a string use the `Replace` method:

```
string s = "This text contains white spaces";
string ns = s.Replace(" ", "");
```

This will create this string: `"Thistextcontainswhitespaces"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
s= s.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

Or using Regex

```
s= Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", String.Empty);
```

Comment: I recommend `String.Replace` if you know the whitespace will always be a space character (ASCII 32). Regular expressions have much more overhead.